# Conversion between any two of MS office Word, Excel, PowerPoint and Adobe PDF

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, ms-office, openxml

Need to be able to convert between any two of the four types (MS Word, Excel, PowerPoint and PDF), the libraries currently in use are Aspose.Words to create word, itextsharp to deal with PDF and openxml is used to create PowerPoint, but it looks like none of those can do the conversion job, the docs do not have a fixed template, any recommendations on a C# library that can achieve this?

Comment: Thanks @K J! Need to do it though C# program and the docs are not with fixed templates.

Comment: You may take a look at: https://www.e-iceblue.com/Introduce/spire-office-for-net.html

Comment: Thanks @DheerajMalik for your recommendation!

Answer (score 0):

I found that [GroupDocs.Conversion for .NET](https://products.groupdocs.com/conversion/net/) suits what I need.